# What is the result of divide by zero?

Tags: theory, divide-by-zero

To be clear, I am not looking for NaN or infinity, or asking what the answer to `x/0` should be. What I'm looking for is this:

Based on how division is performed in hardware (I do not know how it is done), if division were to be performed with a divisor of 0, and the processor just chugged along happily through the operation, what would come out of it?

I realize this is highly dependent on the dividend, so for a concrete answer I ask this: What would a computer spit out if it followed its standard division operation on `42 / 0`?

**Update:**

I'll try to be a little clearer. I'm asking about the actual operations done with the numbers at the bit level to reach a solution. The result of the operation is just bits. NaN and errors/exceptions come into play when the divisor is discovered to be zero. If the division actually happened, what bits would come out?

Comment: Off-topic: belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: NaN would come out. What, did you think computers were hiding the real result from us?

Comment: @AlastairPitts Are you sure? Since it's about how a processor would handle the operation, it seems more suited for here than a purely math site.

Comment: Chip instructions are hard coded logic gates, made out of raw materials etched into silicon, the actual layout of which is likely unique to each architecture.  I think we're all speculating here.  We would have to know the internal IC schematic for a particular processor - *and what would happen if part of that schematic were removed* in order to answer this accurately.  But yeah, they've hard-coded in the 0-divisor check.  What might get you somewhere is learning how newer computer architectures implement their divide logic.

Comment: Voting OT.  From the FAQ - "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"

Comment: @Jim: My mistake, I misunderstood the scope of the question. Still not sure it's on topic for SO (even through it's been successfully answered)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might just *not halt*. Integer division can be carried out in linear time through repeated subtraction: for 7/2, you can subtract 2 from 7 a total of 3 times, so that’s the quotient, and the remainder (modulus) is 1. If you were to supply a dividend of 0 to an algorithm like that, unless there were a mechanism in place to prevent it, the algorithm would not halt: you can subtract 0 from 42 an infinite number of times without ever getting anywhere.

From a type perspective, this should be intuitive. The result of an undefined computation *or* a non-halting one is ⊥ (“bottom”), the undefined value inhabiting every type. Division by zero is not defined on the integers, so it should rightfully produce ⊥ by raising an error or failing to terminate. The former is probably preferable. ;)

Other, more efficient (logarithmic time) division algorithms rely on series that converge to the quotient; for a dividend of 0, as far as I can tell, these will either fail to converge (i.e., fail to terminate) or produce 0. See [Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29) on Wikipedia.

Floating-point division similarly needs a special case: to divide two floats, subtract their exponents and integer-divide their significands. Same underlying algorithm, same problem. That’s why there are representations in IEEE-754 for positive and negative infinity, as well as signed zero and NaN (for 0/0).

Comment: It *could* be carried out through repeated subtraction, but it isn't in practice...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Right. I was editing to add a note about other algorithms.

Comment: Even with long division, the hardware will terminate.  It will perform a fixed number of stages.

Answer (score 8):

For processors that have an internal "divide" instruction, such as the x86 with `div`, the CPU actually causes a software interrupt if one attempts to divide by zero. This software interrupt is usually caught by the language runtime and translated into an appropriate "divide by zero" exception.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question as asked.

Comment: Yes, the question has been edited since my answer. I've +1'd yours.

Answer (score 5):

Hardware dividers typically use a pipelined [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) structure.

Assuming we're talking about integer division for now (as opposed to floating-point); the first step in long division is to align the most-significant ones (before attempting to subtract the divisor from the dividend).  Clearly, this is undefined in the case of 0, so who knows what the hardware would do.  If we assume it does something sane, the next step is to perform log(n) subtractions (where n is the number of bit positions).  For every subtraction that results in a positive result, a 1 is set in the output word.  So the output from this step would be an all-1s word.

Floating-point division requires three steps:

- Taking the difference of the exponents
- Fixed-point division of the mantissas
- Handling special cases

0 is represented by all-0s (both the mantissa and the exponent).  However, there's always an implied leading 1 in the mantissa, so if we weren't treating this representation as a special case, it would just look and act like an extremely small power of 2.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were some machines where a divide by zero instruction would freeze up the execution unit until a supervisory timer circuit recognized a fault.  Adding hardware to "cleanly" avoid having an attempt to divide by zero get stuck would make a computer more expensive, so I wouldn't be surprised if some machines didn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation.  IEE standard 754 floating point[1] defines signed infinity values, so in theory that should be the result of divide by zero.  The hardware simply sets a flag if the demoninator is zero on a division operation.  There is no magic to it.

Some erroneous (read x86) architectures throw a trap if they hit a divide by zero which is in theory, from a mathematical point of view, a cop out.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: No, "from a mathematical point of view" you can't divide by 0. NEVER. It just isn't defined. What we call "infinity" is a symbol to represent an arbitrary large number that is the result of dividing "something" by almost 0 (but not 0)

Answer (score 1):

It would be an infinite loop. Typically, division is done through continuous subtraction, just like multiplication is done via continual addition.

So, zero is special cased since we all know what the answer is anyway.

Comment: Really? Multiplication and division are linear-time operations?

Answer (score 1):

It would actually spit out an exception. Mathematically, 42 / 0, is undefined, so computers won't spit out a specific value to these inputs. I know that division can be done in hardware, but well designed hardware will have some sort of flag or interrupt to tell you that whatever value contained in the registers that are supposed to contain the result is not valid. Many computers make an exception out of this.

Comment: Also, I'm writing this comment to preclude anyone from saying that 42 / 0 is actually infinity. BLASPHEMY! 42 / X tends to infinity when X tends to 0, but 42 / 0 is just undefined. Big difference.

Comment: Totally true, 42/x = oo is just a symbol to represent an arbitrary large number: "The result grows as x gets closer to 0"

Answer (score 1):

**On x86, interrupt 0 occurs and the output registers are unchanged**

Minimal 16-bit real mode example (to be added to a bootloader for example):

```
    movw $handler, 0x00
    movw %cs, 0x02
    mov $0, %ax
    div %ax
    /* After iret, we come here. */
    hlt
handler:
    /* After div, we come here. *
    iret
```

[How to run this code in detail](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/9e58c1dc656dab54aa69daa38f84eb8c0aa6151e/interrupt_zero_divide.S) || [32-bit version](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d5d35fc39a21c597b6149d72abc36a2294aba1b6/idt_zero_divide.S).

The Intel documentation for the DIV instruction does not say that the regular output registers (`ax` == result, `dx` == module) are modified, so I think this implies they stay unchanged.

Linux would then handle that interrupt to send a SIGFPE to the process that did that, which is will kill it if not handled.

Answer (score -1):

X / 0 Where X is an element of realnumbers and is greater than or equal to 1,
therefor the answer of X / 0 = infinity.

Division method (c#)

```
Int Counter = 0; /* used to keep track of the division */
Int X = 42;      /* number */
Int Y = 0;       /* divisor */
While (x > 0) { 
    X = X - Y; 
    Counter++;
}
Int answer = Counter;
```

Comment: "I'm asking about the actual operations done with the numbers at the bit level to reach a solution." -OP.